# 「一切...ない。」「さっぱり...ない」「少しも..ない」の違い

Tags: word-choice

「一切...ない。」「さっぱり...ない」「少しも..ない」の違いを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: さっぱり...ないは他二つと比べると少しだけ抽象的、限定されるかもしれないです。

Answer (score 3):

> 「(A) 一切...ない。」「(B) さっぱり...ない」「(C) 少しも..ない」の違い

- 「(A) **一切**...ない」と「(B) **さっぱり**...ない」は、英語の definitely not というフレーズのdefinitley に近い「きっぱりとした断定的な」ニュアンスがあると思う。ニュアンスは、「一切」と「さっぱり」のシラブル（音節）の数が「少しも」より少ないことと、撥音を持つことに起因していると思われる。我々日本人はこの促音にパチンとバネがはじくような勢いを感じる。
  *"(A) **一切**...ない" and "(B) **さっぱり**...ない" have a nuance similar to "definitley" in a phrase "definitely not" in English*.
  *I think there is a "きっぱりとした断定的な definitely assertive" nuance in them.
  This nuance seems to be due to the fact that the number of syllables  of "A" and "B" is less than "C", and that the former two have "[sokuon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokuon) [促音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%83%E9%9F%B3) a kind of geminate consonant"*. *Japanese people feel like the momentum of a sound that is emitted when a leaf spring reverses to "sokuon"*.
- 「(A) **一切**...ない」と「(B) **さっぱり**...ない」とを比べると、前者は一般的に使えるが、後者は口語表現である。
  *When comparing "(A) **一切**...ない" and "(B) **さっぱり**...ない", the former can be used generally but the latter is a colloquial expression*.
- 「(B) **さっぱり**...ない」は、江戸っ子（東京人）の代表的な言い方で、他の２つの表現に比べて、「...」の部分には圧倒的に「分から」か「知ら」が入る。但し江戸っ子は、「さっぱり分からない」「さっぱり知らない」ではなく、「**さっぱり分かんねぇ**」「**さっぱり知らねぇ**」と言う。
  *"(B) **さっぱり** ...ない" is a typical way of an expression used by [Edokko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edokko) [江戸っ子](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%9F%E6%88%B8%E3%81%A3%E5%AD%90) (Tokyoite)*.
  *(B), compared with (A) and (C), is overwhelmingly used as "さっぱり分｛わ｝からない" or "さっぱり知｛し｝らない"*. *However,Tokyoites say "**さっぱり分かんねぇ**" and "**さっぱり知らねぇ**" in stead of saying "さっぱり分からない" and "さっぱり知らない" respectively according to their relaxed and informal pronunciation method*.
- 「(A) **一切**...ない」と「(C) **少しも**..ない」とを比べると、両方とも一般的に使えるが、後者の方が若干口語的なニュアンスが強く、また、前者に比べてやや「ない」の程度が弱い感じがする。
  *Comparing "(A) **一切**...ない" with "(C) **少しも**...ない", both are commonly used in various cases, but the latter has a slightly colloquial nuance, 
  and the degree of "not/nothing" is a little weaker*.

Answer (score 1):

mackygoo has altready explained it.

In my opinion,

No more conflicts between us at all.

一切わだかまりはない。

さっぱりわだかまりはない。strange?

少しもわだかまりはない。

I can't get it at all.

一切分からない。

さっぱりわからない。

少しも分からない。

I have never met him.

一切彼に会ったことはない。

さっぱり彼に会ったことはない strange

少しも彼に会ったことはない strange